# how to change textcolor in textfield when I add a row in tableview

Tags: swift4, xcode9, xcode9.2, swift4.1

I have two buttons.one is @addIncomeTapped and the other one is @addExpenseTapped.what I want to do is to change the textcolor in my textfield once the user tapped (for example) the addIncomeTapped button. I'm trying to figure it out but have no luck :'( I'm hoping someone can help me? I'm still trying to learn swift more.thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
class MySecondCell:UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate
{    
    @IBOutlet weak var budgetTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var budgetAmount: UITextField!
}

class secondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

   var textfield: UITextField!    
   var SecondBudgetName = [String]()

   @IBOutlet weak var balanceView: UIView!
   @IBOutlet weak var mytableView: UITableView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mytableView.delegate = self
    mytableView.dataSource = self

    view.addVerticalGradientLayer(topColor: primaryColor, bottomColor: secondaryColor)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func addIncomeTapped(_ sender: Any) {
print("Add income tapped")
    //Add new row
    insert()
}

@IBAction func addExpenseTapped(_ sender: Any) {
print("Add expense tapped")
    //Add new row
    insert()

}

func insert(){
    SecondBudgetName.append("\(SecondBudgetName.count + 1)")
    let insertionIndexPath = IndexPath(row: SecondBudgetName.count - 1 , section: 0)
    mytableView.insertRows(at: [insertionIndexPath], with: .automatic)
}

//Configure TableView

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        SecondBudgetName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return SecondBudgetName.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = mytableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "budgetCell") as! MySecondCell

    return cell

}

}
```

[here is my tableviewcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3qGS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First class names start with capital.
2. Second, about your code you will need to add some pieces of code:
3. On `secondViewController`  you will add two other declarations,
   `var budgetTitleTextFieldColor = UIColor.black` since black is default color for text or whatever color you're using
   `var budgetAmountTextFieldColor = UIColor.black` same as `budgetTitleTextFielColor`
4. Add to

   ```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = mytableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "budgetCell") as! MySecondCell
   cell.budgetTitle.textColor = budgetTitleTextFieldColor
   cell.budgetAmount.textColor = budgetAmountTextFieldColor
   return cell
   }
   ```
5. Then in button actions

   ```
   @IBAction func addIncomeTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       print("Add income tapped")
       //Add new row
       insert()
       // here you change the colors we declared in the beginning, it depends which one you want to change
       budgetTitleTextFieldColor = UIColor.whateverYourColorIs
       budgetAmountTextFieldColor = UIColor.whateverYourColorIs
       // don't forget this
       tableView.reloadData()}
    @IBAction func addExpenseTapped(_ sender: Any) {
          print("Add expense tapped")
          //Add new row
          insert()
          // here you change the colors we declared in the beginning
          budgetTitleTextFieldColor = UIColor.whateverYourColorIs
          budgetAmountTextFieldColor = UIColor.whateverYourColorIs
          // don't forget this
         tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```

Comment: thankyousomuch for the reply.i tried what you said but once I add "tableView.reloadData()"im getting this error "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)" .am i missing some code?

Comment: Your table view is named myTableView, so you have to change tableView.reloadData() to myTableView.reloadData()

Comment: im sorry for asking so many questions but. why does the previous rows that I added also change.for example. i already have 5 inserted rows. and once I tapped the "add expense button" all the textcolors in rows becomes red, same as the "add income button" it all turns to green. :( maybe I should replace the reloadData. but I don't know what to use.

Comment: Since you reload table view data, every row will get reloaded and every row will get the colour as you set it. So which row colour do you want to change?

Comment: what I want to do is. when I press "add income button" the text color of it will stay green. and when I press "add expense button" the new inserted rows text color will also stay red.

Comment: I don't know if I understood you properly, but try this in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` add this `if indexPath.row == SecondBudgetName.count - 1 { // here set the color } else { // use default color }`